# How To Send Spaces To MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which contains some checkboxes and in one of the checkboxes, it contains a value of 'Liberal Democrats'. Once I submit this off to the database, the value isnt recorded as it has a space in it. How do I fix this problem? The following is the relevant bits of my form:

```
    <label>Party Standing For Election</label>
  <input name="Conservatives" type="checkbox" value="Conservatives" /> Conservative
  <input name="Liberal Democrats" type="checkbox" value="Liberal Democrats" /> Liberal Democrats
  <input name="Labour" type="checkbox" value="Labour"  /> Labour
```

it goes to this php page:

```
    <?php

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$month = $_REQUEST['month'];
$year = $_REQUEST['year'];
$labour = $_REQUEST['Labour'];
$libdems = $_REQUEST['Liberal Democrats'];
$conservatives = $_REQUEST['Conservatives'];


$con = mysql_connect("****************************");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('******', $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO elections (name_of_election, date, month, year, party1, party2, party3) VALUES ('$name','$date', '$month','$year','$labour', '$libdems', '$conservatives')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else 
  {
      echo '<h2>An Election Has Been Created</h2>';

  }
?>
```

help?

Comment: please show us the SQL CREATE syntax for table `elections`

Comment: I prefer to vote for the `'); DROP TABLE elections; --` party myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow @seanbreeden's answer for fixing your main issue, but make the following changes to protect your form from SQL injection by @CanSpice:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['date']);
$month = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['month']);
$year = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['year']);
$labour = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Labour']);
$libdems = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['LiberalDemocrats']);    // with updated change
$conservatives = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Conservatives']);
// ...
$sql="INSERT INTO elections (`name_of_election`, `date`, `month`, `year`, `party1`, `party2`, `party3`) VALUES ('$name','$date', '$month','$year','$labour', '$libdems', '$conservatives')";
```

Comment: Good advice!  You should definitely do this.

Comment: That doesn't completely do it. Use placeholders as well.

Comment: hey araon, thanks for that. I thought that the SQL attacks can only happen if the user gets a chance to enter some sql statements in any boxes provided to them. my form only contains checkboxes and drop downs, so how could they possibly do anything? thanks

Comment: Probably can't directly from your form if it's all checkboxes, but someone could always simulate a form submit to your page.

Comment: Moved from my answer for reference:  Just change the name of the control to LiberalDemocrats <input name="LiberalDemocrats" and change $libdems = $_REQUEST['Liberal Democrats']; to $libdems = $_REQUEST['LiberalDemocrats'];. You can leave the value as Liberal Democrats with the space in it.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody can edit the HTML of your web page to put arbitrary strings into your application, even if you don't provide them an easy means to do so. Any data sent to you over the network should be regarded as hostile even if you believe you control the sender.